# Find errors in a sequence

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

I have an activity changelog of officers that become active/inactive.

```
OfficerID  ChangeTo   ChangeDate
1          active     2017-05-01
1          active     2017-05-02
1          inactive   2017-05-04
6          active     2013-09-09
6          inactive   2016-04-14
6          recruit    2016-06-22
6          active     2016-06-23
6          inactive   2017-04-30
```

In the case above, officer id 1 is active from 1st of May until the 4th of May.

This is essentially a 'housekeeping' task.  The second row is not required and should be deleted.  I would like to do this within a MySQL procedure that is linked an event on a schedule.  I need a query that can identify these rows, but I'm not sure how.

In a previous system, I had looped through an ordered list and compared the current value against the previous row's value.  I have read that loops in MySQL are not encouraged, so I'm trying to figure out how to do this with queries alone.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT
    a.ActivityID, a.OfficerID, a.ChangeTo, a.ChangeDate
FROM
    tbl_Officers_Activity as a
    INNER JOIN tbl_Officers_Activity AS b
        ON a.OfficerID = b.OfficerID
        AND a.ChangeDate > b.ChangeDate
        AND a.ChangeTo = b.ChangeTo
    INNER JOIN tbl_Officers_Activity AS c
        ON a.OfficerID = c.OfficerID
        AND a.ChangeDate < c.ChangeDate
        AND a.ChangeTo <> c.ChangeTo
ORDER BY
    OfficerID,
    ChangeDate;
```

I was hoping I could somehow embed the criteria I need into the joins, but I'm at a loss.  any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need

[SQLFIddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5cf370/16)

```
select a1.officerid,a1.changedate,a1.changeto_a as changeto
From 
(select a.officerid,a.changedate,max(a.changeto) as changeto_a,count(*) as rnk
from tbl_Officers_Activity a
inner join tbl_Officers_Activity b
on a.OfficerID=b.OfficerID
and a.ChangeDate>=b.ChangeDate
group by a.officerid,a.changedate) a1
left join
(select a.officerid,a.changedate,max(a.changeto) as changeto_b,count(*) +1 as rnk
from tbl_Officers_Activity a
inner join tbl_Officers_Activity b
on a.OfficerID=b.OfficerID
and a.ChangeDate>=b.ChangeDate
group by a.officerid,a.changedate) b1
on a1.officerid=b1.officerid
and a1.rnk=b1.rnk 
where changeto_a = changeto_b
```

Explanation:

MySQL doesn't have `row_Number` function, so first I had to derive it. I used this query to get `row_number`, which is names as `rnk` in the query. Call the table `a1`.

```
(select a.officerid,a.changedate,max(a.changeto) as changeto_a,count(*) as rnk
from tbl_Officers_Activity a
inner join tbl_Officers_Activity b
on a.OfficerID=b.OfficerID
and a.ChangeDate>=b.ChangeDate
group by a.officerid,a.changedate)
```

Now as MySQL doesn't have `LEAD` function also, I derived it by using the above query again, and changing the `rnk` to `rnk+1`, calling it `b1`.

Now to replicate `LEAD`, I `left joined` `a1` with `b1`

Now using a where clause to find same `changeto`, you can get your output.

Comment: Thank-you for your input.  I ended up with a solution similar to yours, but when running with more data, your solution came back inaccurate.  I'm interested in understanding why this would be the case.  Are you able to spare any thoughts on this matter?

Comment: IF possible, use the fiddle which I gave and add some rows to replicate the incorrect behavior. It is not very evident from the screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

My solution in the end was similar to what Utsav posted, however, after comparing his solution to mine, I found mine to be accurate, and his inaccurate.[image: solution results comparison]

For my solution, I create a temporary table for the initial ordered list with an auto incremental primary key.  Then clone the temp table and join on itself with the primary pk equal to itself +1 and also equal to the status change.

my procedure ends up like this:

```
-- create temp table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_act;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_act (
    AutoID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  ActivityID INT(11),
  OfficerID INT(11),
  ChangeTo text
);

-- temp data
insert into tmp_act (ActivityID,OfficerID,ChangeTo)
    SELECT
        a.ActivityID, a.OfficerID, a.ChangeTo
    FROM
        tbl_Officers_Activity as a
    ORDER BY
        OfficerID,
        ChangeDate;

-- housekeeping
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_act1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_act2;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_act1 AS (SELECT * FROM tmp_act);
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_act2 AS (SELECT * FROM tmp_act);
SELECT
    a.AutoID, a.ActivityID, a.OfficerID, a.ChangeTo
FROM
    tmp_act1 as a
    INNER JOIN tmp_act2 AS b
        ON a.OfficerID = b.OfficerID
        AND a.ChangeTo = b.ChangeTo
        AND a.AutoID = b.AutoID+1;
```